# MySQL knex math operation

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm using knex with node.js I want to do a math query
(I want to add +1 to already existing values)

**I want to do this in knex**

```sql
UPDATE fares SET fare=fare + 70
```

**This is my query in knex, all I get is 0 in the database**

```
knex('table').update({ fares: 'fares' + 70}).then(function() {});
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `.raw()`, although it will work fine. There is built-in capability to increment using `.increment()`. See: [doc link](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-increment)

Sample from the docs:

```
knex('accounts')
  .where('userid', '=', 1)
  .increment('balance', 10)
```

... and, using your table/field names, and a value variable for the update amount.

```
knex('fares')
  .increment('fare', fareIncrementAmount)
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
knex('table').update({
  fares: knex.raw('?? + 70', ['fares'])
})
```

Comment: also how can i pass in a variable instead of the hardcoded 70    
knex.raw('?? + number', ['fares']); ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since the table name is 'fares' then the approriate answer should be :

```
var number = 70;
knex('fares')
    .update({
        fare: knex.raw(`?? + ${number}`, ['fare'])
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

See ? you can pass your any value to that number now

Answer (score 0):

In knex it's just operate as `string plus number`, change it to:

```
knex('table').update({ fares: '`fares` + 70'}).then(function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are built-in methods to achieve this,

**1. Increments**

The Increment method will help you to increment column value by some specific value, consider the example from official docs,

```
knex('accounts').where('userid', '=', 1).increment('balance', 5)
```

> Outputs: update `accounts` set `balance` = `balance` + 5 where `userid` = 1

**2. Decrements**

```
knex('accounts').where('userid', '=', 1).decrement('balance', 5)
```

> Outputs: update `accounts` set `balance` = `balance` - 5 where `userid` = 1

However, I didn't find methods for `multiplication` or `division`. We can do it by the `raw query` as given below,

```
knex.raw('update accounts set balance = (balance * ? ) where id = ?', [10 , 1]).then(function(resp) { ... });
```

> Outputs: update accounts set balance = (balance * 10) where id = 1;

The same raw query should work for the division as well.